# Quiz with multiple answers

Tags: python, csv

I am currently in the process of making a quiz in Python, all the questions are stored in a csv database. I am having difficulty in having multiple answers to one question in the quiz.

Note: I do not have the code on this computer so I quickly made something up along the lines below:

```
file=open("easydatabase.csv","r")
answer = input("\n" + detail[0])
    for line in file:
        details=line.split(",")
        if details[1] == answer:
            print("Correct! Added 1 to your score.")
```

The main issue I am having is having the correct answer to be equal to multiple cells in the csv file.

(I was trying different things such as writing `details[1,2]` but I had no luck)

Comment: Please read about creating a [mcve] and provide an example of the file format for `easydatabase.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know which specific cells the answers are in, you can use an "or" or "and" conditional in your **if statement**, depending on what kind of answers you will take.

If you're looking for **any** matching answers in the "details" list, you can loop through the "details" list with a conditional if statement containing what you're looking for.

Comment: I was attempting to use an or statement (this is what I wrote): 

if answer == (details[1]) or (details[2]) but it would allow me to input any answer and it told me it was correct

Comment: I edited the comment above, try using an "and" statement.

Comment: Using an and statement would mean both answers would need to be inputted, sorry if I phrased it poorly but there is a question and there are multiple answers to the question

Comment: Then it needs to be an "or" statement, with a conditional looking like the following:
`if answer == details[1] or answer == details[2]:`

Answer (score 0):

So if you want it to check for a match in multiple items you can use `in`. Something like this:

```
answer = 'correct answer'
multiple_choice = ['wrong answer', 'also wrong', 'correct answer']
if answer in multiple_choice:
    print("Correct! Added 1 to your score.")
```

Comment: I need to use a database (I'm using a csv) where the questions and the answers are both stored in, I would love to make an array but that is the task sadly.

Comment: That should still work for how you want to use it, if you wanted you could do `if  answer in details[1:]` to check against every item except the first

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood the structure of your file that is. When you line split, _details_ is a list of all items in that line. Assuming you have column 1 as the user's answer and the other columns have correct answers, you can still use `in` check if the single answer is in multiple. If not then please give more details on your csv.